# FileReader Thumbnail Preview On Multiple (single) File Fields

Tags: javascript, filereader, reset, preview

Whats the best way to apply javascript to multiple (single) file upload fields, this currently works great on one single field but is targeting the ID and I'm assuming there's a more elegant way to write javascript than repeating for each ID?:

```js
function PreviewImage() {
  var oFReader = new FileReader();
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

  oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
    document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
    document.getElementById('uploadPreview-container').style.display = 'block';
  };
};

function ResetImage() {
  document.getElementById('uploadPreview-container').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('uploadImage').value = '';
};
```

```css
#uploadPreview {
  width: 100px;
}

#uploadPreview-container {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

#uploadReset {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="uploadPreview-container">
  <img id="uploadPreview" />
  <div id="uploadReset"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ResetImage()" title="Reset Image Upload">RESET</a></div>
</div>
<div><input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" data-max-size="248" onChange="PreviewImage();" /></div>
```

Comment: when posting on SO you can hit the button that looks like `<>` and make your code runnable so we can see what it does :)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you will have to use a classname instead of an id, and becuase you don't know how many images will be added you will have to create the `img` elements dynamically.

1. Add a `multiple` attribute that allows the user to upload more than one image in a single file input.
2. Loop thru the files and append an image preview for each one.

```js
function PreviewImage() {
  Array.from(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files).forEach(file=>{
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = oFREvent.target.result;
      img.className = "uploadPreview";
      document.getElementById("preview_div").appendChild(img);
      document.getElementById('uploadPreview-container').style.display = 'block';
    };
  });
};

function ResetImage() {
  document.getElementById('uploadPreview-container').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('uploadImage').value = '';
};
```

```css
.uploadPreview {
  width: 100px;
}

#uploadPreview-container {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

#uploadReset {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="uploadPreview-container">
  <div id=preview_div></div>
  <div id="uploadReset"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ResetImage()" title="Reset Image Upload">RESET</a></div>
</div>
<div><input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" data-max-size="248" onChange="PreviewImage();" multiple /></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works but I ideally wanted to use multiple single file upload fields rather than a multiple file field

Comment: @user3131345 ok then try something. I'm not a free code writing service. show some effort to try it yourself and I'll help you fix it of it doesn't work.